# does Facebook timeline android use scrollview or listview?

Tags: android, facebook, listview, scrollview, facebook-timeline

I'm developing a small application like facebook timeline, but I don't know it use srollview or listview. Can you tell me that?

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely using ListView, which is implemented to handle a ScrollView of homogeneous items including all the view re-usage and re-painting.
Doing it with a ScrollView would need you to handle that from scratch.